# "ART FXR" reverb rack unit has a howling or whistling sound

Tags: audio-engineering

Hello to all audio engineering and repair experts.

I have a very old Applied Research Technology FXR digital effects processing unit. It's a double-processor unit that can function as dual mono (i.e. two different effects for each input/output). A glance inside the board reveals sophisticated circuitry that looks more complicated than a younger Zoom 1201 that I also opened up (just for comparison).

Problem is, it has a howling or whistling sound that pollutes the noisefloor of my sound mixes. Can anybody offer an insight on where it might be coming from?

The best work-around is upping the input and lowerin the output, and maximizing the send level coming from my analog board.

To compare, if I run my reverb sends through the Zoom, my noisefloor is at -88db. If I use the ART FXR (the subject of this post), the noisefloor is at -70db. I would very much like to repair this unit - would be a great shame to junk it.

Comment: When did it start? What did you change at that time?

Comment: @SolarMike, it's always been this way. I got this for free. It's 3rd hand already with me. The only thing I changed was replace the BR battery that maintains memory for changing presets.